# Formatted text on UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I struck with a small thing i think so, in my app `UITextView` plays important role. So i like to add formatting feature (Bold, Italics, underline) to it.

Once i tried using,

```
[NotesTxtView setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];
```

it works fine but when i save the data to `db` the formatted texts change to normal. What can i do for that?

Is there any solution for my problem?

Helpers are appreciated,..

Comment: Do you save formatted text as plain string?

Comment: yes,. I just add that line above only,.. While editing the text changes but when i reopen it goes to plain text

Comment: YOu will need to save it as an attributedText

Comment: @GenieWanted Can you post code for that,..

Comment: Nanbha.. how are you saving the text to your DB? Just show me that code..

Comment: macha only like plain text,.. NSString *notes = NotesTxtView.text;  INSERT INTO TableName(notes, '%@'),notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save style information also. NSAttributedString's method `dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:` will help:

> Returns an data object that contains a text stream corresponding to the characters and attributes within the given range.

So you save and restore NSData object from db.

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType};

// export data
NSData *data =
[self.textView.attributedText
 dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.textView.text.length)
 documentAttributes:attrs
 error:nil];

...
// save data to db, fetch later
...

// restore
self.textView.attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithData:data
 options:nil
 documentAttributes:&attrs
 error:nil];
```

Consider using other document types (all available from iOS 7):

```
NSString *NSPlainTextDocumentType;
NSString *NSRTFTextDocumentType;
NSString *NSRTFDTextDocumentType;
NSString *NSHTMLTextDocumentType;
```

Comment: Thanks, Once i tried this and get back to you vokilam

Comment: I cant find this dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error method in NSMutableString